# Unable to locate image when creating container Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry, azure-container-apps

I created an Azure Container Registry (Region is CentralCanada) and then uploaded a docker image from Visual Studio for an .Net 6.0, Web API project.

After the Linux image was deployed successfully I am able to see it within my Azure Container.

Then I attempt to create a Container App (Environment is also set to CentralCanada) and at the point where I assign an image, I choose Azure Container Registry and it displays my container registry by correct name, however it says no images found.

Why don't I see my image that is in my Azure Container Registry.

I am able to create a container app using the default HelloWorld app.

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, please use the check mark to identify it as the accepted answer. Otherwise, please share with us how you overcame your issue or let us know if your issue persists.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue.  I was able to fix it by navigating to Container Registry > Access keys.  Then enable Admin user.